# MongoDB - latitude/longitude - signs

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

Reading here

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-a-2dsphere-index/

I find the following:

> The following example queries grid coordinates and returns all documents 
>   within a 10 mile radius of longitude 88 W and latitude 30 N. The example 
>   converts the distance, 10 miles, to radians by dividing by the approximate 
>   radius of the earth, 3959 miles:

```
db.places.find( { loc :
                  { $geoWithin :
                    { $centerSphere :
                       [ [ 88 , 30 ] , 10 / 3959 ]
                } } } )
```

I think the "standard" notation is:
East is + (plus) and West is - (minus),
North is + (plus) and South is - (minus).

So why is West + (plus) in this example
on the MongoDB documentation site?
Is it really that way in MongoDB?

In fact, is there any standard which defines if West
maps to + or to - and the same for East, North, South?

See also:
[Wikipedia - Latitude and longitude of the Earth](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/Latitude_and_Longitude_of_the_Earth.svg)
[Wikipedia - Geographic coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system)

Comment: it's an error in the documentation.  I just submitted a pull request to have it fixed.  It should be either -88 or it should say 88 E. https://github.com/mongodb/docs/pull/1694

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Thanks, I also suspected so but decided to ask anyway.